# Derived Node class

Tags: c++

I have Base class, Derived class, and then Node class, which is derived from the Derived class. Usually, I would do struct Node, where I'd have Object object (as a data in the node). But, in the case of derived Node class that would make no sense, as constructor of Derived has already been called. So, my question is - how do I assign data to the nodes?

```
class Base
{
    payload;
};

class Derived : public Base
{
    payload;
};

class Node : public Derived
{
    Node(Object & object);
    /*
    Previously I'd have struct with Object object_, and I 
    would do object = object_ (which would call an overload to
    make a deep copy). But, in this case we already have an instance 
    of Derived, and making another one doesn't seem right. 
    So, my question is to how access that instance to assign 
    passed object to it? Or am I doing something completely stupid?
    */
}
```

Comment: `Node(Object &object) : Derived(object) {}` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either you can `type conversion`(class to class) or `copy constructor`.

```
class Node : public Derived
{
        public:
                Node() {
                }
                /** type conversion operator **/
                operator Derived() {
                        /**  code **/
                }
                /** copy constructor **/
                Node(Node &nd_obj) : Derived(Derived d_obj){    
                        cout<<"Node copy const called "<<endl;
                        cout<<"payload = "<<nd_obj.payload<<endl;
                }
};
int main() {
        Derived d1;
        Node Nd1;
        d1 = Nd1;//type conversion

        Node Nd2 = d1;//copy constructor, make sure exact match is there

}
```